# Threading advice for web crawler - scheduling with single list

Tags: python, multithreading, list, web-crawler

I would like to add in multiple threading to my web crawler but I can see that the way the spider schedules links to be crawled may be incompatible with multi-threading. The crawler is only ever going to be active on a handful of news websites but rather than starting a new thread per domain I would prefer to have multiple threads opened on the same domain. My web crawling code is operated through the following function:

```
def crawl_links():
    links_to_crawl.append(domain[0])
    while len(links_to_crawl) > 0:
        link = links_to_crawl[0]
        if link in crawled_links or link in ignored_links:
            del links_to_crawl[0]
        else:
            print '\n', link
            try:
                html = get_html(link)
                GetLinks(html)
                SaveFile(html)
                crawled_links.append(links_to_crawl.pop(0))
            except (ValueError, urllib2.URLError, Timeout.Timeout, httplib.IncompleteRead):
                ignored_links.append(link_to_crawl.pop(0))
    print 'Spider finished!'
    print 'Ignored links:\n', ignored_links
    print 'Crawled links:\n', crawled_links
    print 'Relative links\n', relative_links
```

If my understanding of how threading will work is correct, if I simply opened multiple threads on this process they will all crawl the same links (potentially multiple times) or they will clash a bit. Without necessarily going into specifics, how would you advise to restructure the scheduling to make it compatible with multiple threads running at the same time?

I've given this some thought and the only workaround I could come up with is having the `GetLinks()` class appending links to multiple lists, with an individual list per thread... but this seems like quite a clumsy workaround.

Comment: Threads share the same memory space. This is both a curse and a feature, since it lets you delegate different URLs to different threads (either with one global list that all threads pull from or a local list for each thread, which is harder to manage), but it also means you have to make sure different threads don't corrupt any data structures that are shared between them (since almost no code is thread safe unless explicitly written to be so). A simple way to ensure things work is to use a "lock" or "mutex" to allow only one thread at a time into a critical section of your code (like the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general scheme that I have used in order to run a multi-threaded application in Python.

The scheme takes a table of input arguments, and executes **in parallel** one thread for each row.

Each thread takes one row, and executes **sequentially** one thread for each item in the row.

Each item contains a fixed number of arguments which are passed to the executed thread.

**Input Example:**

```
table = \
[
    [[12,32,34],[11,20,14],[33,67,56],[10,20,45]],
    [[21,21,67],[44,34,74],[23,12,54],[31,23,13]],
    [[31,67,56],[34,22,67],[87,74,52],[87,74,52]],
]
```

In this example we will have 3 threads running in parallel, each one executing 4 threads sequentially.

In order to keep your threads balanced, it is advisable to have the same number of items in each row.

**Threading Scheme:**

```
import threading
import MyClass # This is for you to implement

def RunThreads(outFileName,errFileName):
    # Create a shared object for saving the output of different threads
    outFile = CriticalSection(outFileName)
    # Create a shared object for saving the errors of different threads
    errFile = CriticalSection(errFileName)
    # Run in parallel one thread for each row in the input table
    RunParallelThreads(outFile,errFile)

def RunParallelThreads(outFile,errFile):
    # Create all the parallel threads
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=RunSequentialThreads,args=(outFile,errFile,row)) for row in table]
    # Start all the parallel threads
    for thread in threads: thread.start()
    # Wait for all the parallel threads to complete
    for thread in threads: thread.join()

def RunSequentialThreads(outFile,errFile,row):
    myObject = MyClass()
    for item in row:
        # Create a thread with the arguments given in the current item
        thread = threading.Thread(target=myObject.Run,args=(outFile,errFile,item[0],item[1],item[2]))
        # Start the thread
        thread.start()
        # Wait for the thread to complete, but only up to 600 seconds
        thread.join(600)
        # Terminate the thread if it hasn't completed up to this point
        if thread.isAlive():
            thread._Thread__stop()
            errFile.write('Timeout on arguments: '+item[0]+' '+item[1]+' '+item[2]+'\n')
```

The class below implements an object which can be safely shared among different threads running in parallel. It provides a single interface method called `write`, which allows any thread to update the shared object in a safe manner (i.e., without the OS switching to another thread during the process).

```
import codecs

class CriticalSection:
    def __init__(self,fileName):
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.fileDesc = codecs.open(fileName,mode='w',encoding='utf-8')
    def __del__(self):
        del self.mutex
        self.fileDesc.close()
    def write(self,data):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        self.fileDesc.write(data)
        self.mutex.release()
```

The above scheme should allow you to control the level of "parallel-ness" and the level of "sequential-ness" within your application.

For example, you can use a single row for all the items, and have your application running in a complete sequential manner.

In contrast, you can place each item in a separate row, and have your application running in a complete parallel manner.

And of course, you can choose any combination of the above...

**Note:**

In `MyClass`, you will need to implement method `Run`, which will take the `outFile` and `errFile` objects, as well as the arguments that you have defined for each thread.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been reading and re-reading this code and whilst it's easily laid out to follow and I get some of it, some of the concepts here are quite complicated for a beginner. If possible could you outline for a novice how exactly this works?

Comment: Yes. To begin with, I will change the input format: instead of input files with argument lines, I will place the entire input in a matrix. Second, I will explain some multi-threading issues that you might not by aware of. See revised answer (in a few minutes)...

Comment: Answer revised; please have a look and see if it "makes more sense" to you at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot, made a lot more sense and helped a lot.